# Why does python 3 forbid if-condition after while-loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I've got indentation error in the following code, python 3.9

```
while list1:
    # do smth

if condition: # do smth
```

The error is fixed if I put smth after while loop. It seems, that python 3 forbids if condition after while-loop. Is it a bug or a feature?

```
while list1:
    # do smth

var1 = 0
if condition: # do smth
```

Comment: It's a bug. In your code... please post the full code and the error message.

Comment: There is nothing in your question that indicates that the first syntax is invalid. You might have some whitespace/unprintable characters dangling somewhere in your file.

Comment: The while-statement expects a block after it. If you don't provide it with a block of code (i.e. if you don't have any indented code inside of it), then you break the syntax. So your second example, as currently written in your question, is wrong also.

Comment: If you really want an empty block (for testing purposed for example), you can use the `pass` keyword.

Comment: Please post the actual code that reproduces the problem. As it is now, both snippets have the same error.

Comment: the problem was in hidden spaces, the code worked fine when executed in command line, but in the Editor the error was raised, so I had to pretty the code with some plugin

Answer (score 1):

`#` comments are ignored by the interpreter. In order for the block to be valid it must have at least one statement. This is what `pass` is typically used for:

```
while list1:
    # do smth
    pass

if condition:
    # do smth
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Python expects an indented block after a `while` loop. A commented out section of code does not count. So if you first have this:

```py
while n < 10:
    n += 1
```

and then (e.g. for debugging purposes) comment out the loop body:

```py
while n < 10:
    # n += 1
```

Python will complain:

```
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

If you really wish to comment out the whole loop body of a while loop, temporarily add a dummy `pass` statement:

```py
while n < 10:
    # n += 1
    pass
```